# Should the index be clustered or non-clustered for a md5 column?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, database-design

```
Id, md5, filename
1, 0xc4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b, foo.doc
```

I'm aware that when the column could be frequently edited, the index for the column shouldn't be cluster.
This column never would be modified in my case. But inserting is also a decisive factor, since it's not like an auto increment id which can ensure the latter one is greater than the previous ones.

How do you think about it?

PS: I'm working on SQL Server. The md5 field type is `binary(16)`, not `char(32)`.

Comment: Seems a poor choice for a clustered index in my opinion, but it depends on your normal usage.

Comment: Does the column need an index at all? If so why?

Comment: Do you join or filter on this column? Probably you only need a clustered index on Id and that's already the PK. Whether you do or not depends entirely on your usage, not on just the table.

Comment: @Stu, yes, would do search with the md5. `select * from tb where md5=0x....`

Comment: @DaleK, `select * from tb where md5=0x....`

Comment: @DaleK 16 bytes is not terribly wide for a clustering key, especially if constant lookups are done based on that. What gain would there be in having another surrogate clustering key if you are going to need an index on the `md5` column anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

16 bytes is not terribly wide for a clustering key, especially if constant lookups are done based on that. And you are doing a lot of lookups based on this column and it is never going to change once inserted.

So I would say it's OK to use it as a clustering key. While it's true that the insertion order would be random, and therefore page splits could occur, you can always mitigate that by occasionally rebuilding the clustered index if it is heavily fragmented.

What gain would there be in having another surrogate clustering key if you are going to need an index on the `md5` column anyway?

---

Do bear in mind that MD5 is subject to collision problems, so you may want to use a better hashing method and/or use a surrogate key as a *second* key column (ie clustering on `md5, id`)

Comment: Rebuilding the index is not really useful as it will just re-fragment.  And you need to rebuild it with a fill factor of about 70 to prevent a flurry of page splits after the rebuild.  This index will rarely be range scanned, so aligning the page locations with the sort order isn't going to do much.

Comment: True, but very heavy fragmentation can still be problematic. It will still be seeked a lot, and given there are only three columns in the table it seems to make little sense to have a surrogate clustering key along with another index on the hash column.